# How to add product to cart with product attributes and quantity?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to search some articles on the google but they mentioned to variation products and I don't know what they are. I'm only want to add product to cart with product attribute (or multi attribute) and quantity. I tried this url `<?php echo home_url('/cart/?add-to-cart='.$product->id.'&attribute_mau-sac=#425f70'); ?>` for "a" element but attribute_mau-sac doesn't add to cart width product. My products are simple products. Please help me!

[image: Sample product]

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Are asking about php code?

Comment: @UngNHODAI I updated my article. Does it more clear?

Comment: " I tried this url <?php echo home_url('/cart/?add-to-cart='.$product->id.'&attribute_mau-sac=#425f70'); ?> for "a" element but attribute_mau-sac doesn't add to cart width product" => could you show me your code on cart page?

Comment: Like this article http://www.eggplantstudios.ca/woocommerce-product-variation-add-cart-grid/. In my situation, attribute_mau-sac instead of "volume" (250ml, 500ml ...). They use variable product but I use simple product

Comment: You are using WooCommerce? Did you try to change your product to "variable product"? The simple product might not has "variations array".

Comment: @Ung Are you pro or good knownedge about woo?

Comment: No, I'm not. You should edit your question so everyone know that you are having problem when using Woo.

Comment: =)) I know that. I write question, everyone doesn't understand. It means I gave a wrong question so I need to research more to understand what problem is. And if you are not sure about your answer and what I mean you shouldn't answer it

Comment: I didn't answer your question. All are my comments only.

Comment: Those need to be set as "Used for variations" (there should be a checkbox). If you don't see the checkbox, you need to make sure the "Variable Product" dropdown is active (instead of single product). Then you would set up the variations and save so the user can select a color.

Comment: @Aibrean I actived "Variable Product" but I didn't see "Used for variations" checkbox and I couldn't add variable as tutorial http://www.remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-variable-product-with-variations-to-cart/. You can see my admin here https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZpLtV1DKp_k/VVQGo9PAe2I/AAAAAAAB5AU/4uavEkUGzVs/s0/1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my writeup [here](http://edgewebware.com/2015/05/how-variations-work-woocommerce/) on how variations work.

First off, you want to select “Variable Product” from the “Product Data” dropdown. Simple product is the default output.

[image: Product Variation selection]

From there, you need to go to the attributes menu. This allows you to have both global attributes than be applied to a product (set in the Products > Attributes menu on the left admin sidebar if you want to set globals) or on a per-product basis. You can see I’ve added one for pant pattern. If you want to give the customer the option of selecting it and it appearing as part of their selection in their order, make sure “Used for variations” is checked.

[image: Attribute Screen]

Once checked, make sure you click the “Save attributes” button. Then you can go to the Variations tab.

[image: Variations Screen]

You can see now that I’ve added variations. This is done by choosing an option (see highlighted area in red), in this case the pant pattern. I did this because the pants affect the price. If they didn’t I could have had it set to “Any Pant Type…” You just need to make sure you have at least one (even if it is "Any" across the board). You can bulk edit the fields available with the “Choose a field to bulk edit…” dropdown. You will need at least one variation to set the Price and shipping (even if it doesn’t matter what variations the customer chooses).

On the front-end, you will see that no “Add to cart” appears without selecting attributes and the variation.

[image: No selection made]

When you make your value selection, the price and “Add to cart” buttons appear.

[image: With selection]

When the attribute for pant type is changed the price adjusts accordingly as well.

[image: Variation change]

Comment: Thanks for your answer